Akka Typed Actor Discovery
I am in the process of learning Akka remoting and clustering. I am not getting the expected behavior when I am trying to send a message to a remote Actor.
Remote Actor deployed on localhost:2552
object SimpleActor {

  def apply(): Behavior[String] = Behaviors.receive { (context, message) =>
    context.log.info(s"Simple Actor System got a message: $message")
    Behaviors.same
  }

  def registerActor(): Behavior[Unit] = Behaviors.setup { context =>
    val simpleActor = context.spawnAnonymous(SimpleActor())
    context.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(MyServiceKey, simpleActor)
    context.log.info(s"Registered SimpleActor to ${MyServiceKey.toString}")

    Behaviors.empty
  }

}

object SimpleActorSystem {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    ActorSystem(SimpleActor.registerActor(), "SimpleActorSystemRemote",
      ConfigFactory.load("part2_remoting/remoteActors.conf").getConfig("remoteSystem"))
  }

}

When the above code is run, I see SimpleActor getting successfully registered to MyServiecKey.
Main actor trying to send a message to remote Actor:
object Pinger {
    def apply(pingService: ActorRef[String], message: String): Behavior[Unit] = Behaviors.setup { _ =>
      pingService ! message
      Behaviors.empty
    }
  }

  object Guardian {

    def apply(): Behavior[Receptionist.Listing] = Behaviors.setup[Receptionist.Listing] { context =>
      context.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Subscribe(MyServiceKey, context.self)

      Behaviors.receiveMessagePartial[Receptionist.Listing] {
        case MyServiceKey.Listing(listings) =>
          println(s"Size of listings: ${listings.size}")
          listings.foreach(ref => context.spawnAnonymous(Pinger(ref, "Hello from Remote Actor!")))
          Behaviors.same
      }

      Behaviors.same
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    ActorSystem(Guardian(), "Guardian")
  }

Configuration details for ActorSystem:
akka {
    actor {
        provider = remote
    }

    remote {
        artery {
            enabled = on
            transport = aeron-udp
            canonical.hostname = "localhost"
            canonical.port = 2551
        }
    }
}

remoteSystem {
    akka {
        actor {
            provider = remote
        }

        remote {
            artery {
                enabled = on
                transport = aeron-udp
                canonical.hostname = "localhost"
                canonical.port = 2552
            }
        }
    }
}

Expected Behavior:
[SimpleActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] INFO part2_remoting.SimpleActor$ -- Simple Actor System got a message: Hello from Remote Actor!

Is clustering required to send a message to an Actor?
Appreciate any help!

Clustering is not required for sending messages to a remote actor (only remoting is required for that: note that clustering is implemented entirely in terms of remoting).  However, using the Receptionist for discovery requires clustering (as it depends on pubsub, which in the distributed case requires clustering).

The Receptionist actor discovery mechanism only propagates registrations when cluster (specifically the Typed cluster) is in use.
However, it is not a requirement that cluster be used when sending messages to a remote ActorSystem: only Remoting is required for that.
Remoting doesn't provide a high-level discovery API for actors: instead, in Classic fashion, you construct a URL for the actor you want to send a message to and convert that into an ActorRef (this is Akka Classic, so in typed, it's effectively an ActorRef[Any]).  If you want to use Remoting without Cluster, it is therefore well advised to steer clear of spawnAnonymous for any actors you want to be able to be directly contacted (without having to implement and use some discovery scheme).
For example, to send a message to an Actor at localhost:2552/user/toplevelChild, you might do something like:
import akka.actor.{ ActorRef => ClassicActorRef }
import akka.actor.RootActorPath
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.adapter.{ ClassicActorRefOps, TypedActorContextOps, TypedActorRefOps }
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }

sealed trait Command
case class ResolvedRemoteActor(ref: ClassicActorRef) extends Command
case class FailedToResolve(cause: Throwable) extends Command

Behaviors.setup[Command] { context =>
  val remotePath = RootActorPath("localhost:2552") / "user" / "topLevelChild"

  val selection = context.toClassic.actorSelection(remotePath)
  implicit val resolveTimeout = 2.seconds

  context.pipeToSelf(selection.resolveOne()) {
    case Success(ref) => ResolvedRemoteActor(ref)
    case Failure(ex) => FailedToResolve(ex)
  }

  Behaviors.receiveMessage { msg =>
    msg match {
      case ResolvedRemoteActor(ref) =>
        context.log.info("Resolved [{}]", ref)

        // Assuming that the target actor can do something with a String
        ref.toTyped[String] ! "hey there!"

        Behaviors.same

      case FailedToResolve(cause) =>
        context.log.warn("Failed to resolve", cause)
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}

Needless to say, especially if using Typed, it's generally just easier to use cluster (Cluster itself does something fairly similar at it's core: see, for instance here and here)
